# metarig is invisible, can't see it (scale, move pose it)

Tags: rigify

I'm a super newbie here. Currently using V 2.91

I started with some tutorials and stuff in youtube and it was all going well until I messed up with some configuration in the process of editing my character and now I can't see my Rig anymore. I tried searching for answers online but nothing worked. Everything seems to be fine and working but I can't manage to see the rig.

I'm going to upload the file and take a screenshot:

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1klVfvf6Vt__D6HR9IAO5_OmDXZZaXRSh/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the screenshot is from this file? There is no metarig in the file. Just be aware, that the cloth of your character is way too dense to animate. It has a few million(!) verts. That's the reason why the blend file is almost 80 MB big.

Comment: Wow! I didn't notice that! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine got what I did to mess up. Really simple, for anyone that might make the same rookie mistake, on the upper right side there's viewport options and "bones" weren't selected. I just clicked and It was back to normal.

[image]